# How to avoid logout after a refresh in Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-material, typescript2.0

I have problem with logout after I refresh the page. I think that problem is in method for getting current user or in method for checking is user admin.

**admin-auth-guard.service.ts**

```
export class AdminAuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkLogin();
}

checkLogin(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.userService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
        map(user => {
            if (user) {
                const isUserAdmin = this.userService.isRoleAdmin();
                if (isUserAdmin) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/forbidden']);
                    return false;
                    
                }
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
            }
        })
    );
}
```

}

**user.service.ts**

```
    export class UserService {
    
      currentUser!: User | null;
    
      private usersUrl = `${SERVER_API_URL}/api/user`;
      private apiServerUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      getCurrentUser(): Observable {
        return this.http.get(`${this.usersUrl}/current-user`);
      }
    
      isRoleAdmin(): boolean {
        if (this.currentUser) {
          return this.currentUser.authorities.some((authority: string) => authority === Authority.ADMIN);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    
      isRoleUser(): boolean {
        if (this.currentUser) {
          return this.currentUser.authorities.some((authority: string) => authority === Authority.USER);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    
      isRoleDeleter(): boolean {
        if (this.currentUser) {
          return this.currentUser.authorities.some((authority: string) => authority === Authority.DELETER);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    
      getStudentsData(userId: number): Observable{
        return this.http.get(`${this.apiServerUrl}/api/user/edit/${userId}`);
      }
    
      updateUser(profesor: Profesors[], userId: number): Observable{
        return this.http.put(`${this.apiServerUrl}/api/user/update/${userId}`, profesor);
      }
    
    }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    
      authenticating = false; // to show loading
      loginFailed = false; // to show login failed message
    
      userCredentials!: UserCredentials;
      private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject(localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") === "true");
    
    
      constructor(
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService
      ) {
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userCredentials = new UserCredentials();
    
      }
    
    
      login() {
        this.authenticating = true;
        this.loginFailed = false;
    
        this.loginService.authenticate(this.userCredentials).subscribe(
          (jwtToken: JwtToken) => this.successfulLogin(jwtToken),
          () => this.loginFailed = true
        ).add(() => this.authenticating = false);
      }
    
      successfulLogin(jwtToken: JwtToken) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', jwtToken.token); // store token value to localstorage
        this.userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe((currentUser: User) => this.userService.currentUser = currentUser);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
      isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return !this.userService.currentUser;
      }
    }
```

**user.model.ts**

```
    export class User {
        id: number;
        username: string;
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        authorities: string[];
    
        constructor(id: number, username: string, firstName: string, lastName: string, authorities: string[]){
            this.id = id;
            this.username = username;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.authorities = authorities;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Depending on how you get the current user, it might return a 403 is the user is not connected. As a result, the Observable will fail. Can you check the network tab in the dev tools ?

Comment: Current-user return 200 in network

Comment: Can you also include the `User` type here? Is it an interface, or a class? My idea is to make sure `User` is a class, and implement the `isRoleAdmin`, `isRoleUser` and `isRoleDeleter` there. This way you also remove the _feature envy_ code smell as well. Then you will be able to call these methods on the `user` instance that you already have, instead of relying on the `UserService` to do that for you. Most likely `UserService.currentUser` is not initialized when you check the roles.

Comment: User is class with constructor

Comment: Do you call this constructor anywhere within the code? I don't see any usage of this constructor

Comment: I do not call constructor anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a bit of refactoring:

Move the role checking methods in the `User` class:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  authorities: string[];

  constructor(user?: Partial<User>) {
    Object.assign(this, user);
  }

  isRoleAdmin = () => {
      return this.authorities.some(authority => authority === Authority.ADMIN);
  }

  isRoleUser = () {
    return this.authorities.some(authority => authority === Authority.USER);
  }

  isRoleDeleter = () {
    return this.authorities.some(authority => authority === Authority.DELETER);
  }
}
```

Then you can remove the role methods from the service, and also make sure to call the `User` class constructor, otherwise it won't be an instance of the `User` class, it will just be a plain object:

```
export class UserService {
  currentUser!: User | null;

  private usersUrl = `${SERVER_API_URL}/api/user`;
  private apiServerUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.usersUrl}/current-user`).pipe(
        map(user => new User(user))
    );
  }

  getStudentsData(userId: number): Observable {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiServerUrl}/api/user/edit/${userId}`);
  }

  updateUser(profesor: Profesors[], userId: number): Observable {
    return this.http.put(
      `${this.apiServerUrl}/api/user/update/${userId}`,
      profesor
    );
  }
}
```

Then, the guard can be implemented like this:

```
export class AdminAuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkLogin();
  }

  checkLogin(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.userService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
      map((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
          return false;
        }
        const isAllowed = user.isRoleAdmin();
        if (!isAllowed) {
          this.router.navigate(["/forbidden"]);
        }
        return isAllowed;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this error:
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[User -> User -> User]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for User!

Comment: Where did you try to inject the user? You should inject the `UserService`, not the `User`.

Comment: Ok, I fix that, but now I got another error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: user.isRoleAdmin is not a function
TypeError: user.isRoleAdmin is not a function

Comment: Then try changing the `User` class as instructed in this response (first code snippet). Make sure to also include the changes I made in the `UserService` as there is the important user mapping, that transforms the plain json object received from the backend into an actual `User` instance.

Answer (score 0):

A thing that I usually do, is save the ID on the localStorage.

When the user logs in, it will save the `id` on localStorage and when you are trying to get anything from that user, just go get the `id` to the localStorage. If you want to logout, just remove the `id` from there, and it's working all fine!

I never had issues with this, and it always worked with me!

**Note:** I only use this way when it is to test something, not when it is suppose to be live

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful if you state explicitly what the problem is or at least describe exactly what you're seeing. Anyway, since I'm not sure, here are some possible solutions:

**Problem 1**

```
  isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return !this.userService.currentUser;
  }
```

This logic is backwards. You're checking if the user is logged in by seeing if this.userService.currentUser is undefined. It needs to check if it's defined.

```
return !!this.userService.currentUser;
```

**Problem 2**
I also don't see where you're setting currentUser. So, all of the checks will fail.

**Problem 3**
It doesn't make sense to check an object with null. An empty User will return true. Instead, declare currentUser like this:

```
currentUser?: User;
```